# panic!() and assert!() in runtime

Tags: runtime, assets

Is there a way, apart from manual code review, to guarantee `assert!()` and `panic!()` calls intended for test code not accidentally gets built for the chain runtime.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

And yeah `debug_assert!` might also be worth keeping in mind. However, you can also do something like:

```rust
macro_rules! test_only_assert {
    ($cond:expr $(,)?) => {{
        #[cfg(test)]
        assert!($cond)
    }};
}

// Now you can do like:
fn runtime_function() {
    test_only_assert!(..)
}
```

And similar for panic too. It will make sure that test will be run even when running with release profile. Eg: `cargo test --all --release` and wont be included if binary is in debug but not in test.

Answer (score 2):

Besides the mentioned `debug_assert!` there is nothing provided by Rust out of the box. However, you could write your own `maybe-assert` crate or whatever you want to call it.

You would by default export a macro `maybe_assert!` with the same semantics as `assert!`, aka you just forward all the arguments to `assert!`. The trick would be to introduce some feature `do-not-assert` or something similar to your `maybe_assert` crate. Then you would enable this `do-not-assert` feature for your runtime when you build a release that should be put on chain.

Answer (score 2):

One way of achieving what you ask for is to enclose every `assert!` statement in a `#cfg[test]`

```
#cfg[test]
assert!(...)
```

Comment: because the code will be less readable and the programmers will forget.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for `debug_assert!()`. It is built into debug builds but not release builds

May not directly answer your question, but could be useful

Comment: Could be, it should assert when we run `cargo test` but not break the runtime